# PostGIS ST_Distance vs. pgRouting

Tags: postgresql, maps, distance, postgis

I am looking to create a city directory web app, and the site will need to be able to calculate distances between two geospatial points (like the distance between the user and a restaurant, or the distance between two restaurants).

I am a newbie to geospatial function, and recently started using PostGIS.  I have been having a heck of a time installing pgRouting into my PostGIS 1.4/PostgreSQL 8.4 server, so am thinking about giving it up for now until I feel like I need it.  I have already spent several hours trying to install pgRouting on my OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard machine with little success.

With that said, what exactly am I giving up?  It seems like ST_Distance will satisfy most of my needs in the short term and things like the Travelling Salesman Problem won't really apply to webapp (at least not for a while, if ever).  Is there something else that I am giving up?  Another reason to use pgRouting?

(As a side note, if you know of a place that makes installing pgRouting easy, please point me in that direction, as I have already tried about 3 pages worth of several google results for tutorials/instructions).

Answer (score 12):

ST_Distance only calculates the distance between two features "as the crow flies". pgRouting on the other hand calculates the actual distance along a network (e.g. road network). Those are two different things and it depends on your use case whether ST_Distance is sufficient or not.

Answer (score 1):

pgRouting can be installed out of the box on OS X 10.6 by downloading packages from: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres

In fact the kyngchaos site delivers packages for postgresql, postgis and their dependencies as frameworks that all work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem with Kyngchaos was that the versions were slightly different than those that my preferred host was to use (A2 Hosting) and I wanted my local dev environment to be as close to the production environment. In the end I decided to use the Kyngchaos installers and suck up the small version difference.